# JavaScript: Add a class specific tag in classList

Tags: javascript, css

I have a class named `X` which has multiple `<span>` inside and I also have a css selector `X span`.

In JavaScript how can I use `X span` instead of `X` in the following case:

```
document.querySelector('.ABC').classList.add(X)
```

I tried `document.querySelector('.ABC').classList.add(X span)` which definitely isn't working.

Comment: What is ".ABC" class?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, are you trying to add multiple classes to one element? `classList.add` is not for selectors, just to add a class.

Comment: I have some css properties for `X span`. I was just wondering rather than adding the whole class in the classList, can I add specific tag properties of a class?

Comment: In the CSS, is it: `X span {.....}`?

Comment: yes `X span {.....}` @zer00ne

Comment: Make sure that you correct that selector by prefixing a dot to the "X" like so: `.X span {...}`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, working with the HTML works like this:

- You ask the browser to give you an object or list of objects that correspond to the HTML elements
- You use the objects to modify the page

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is:

- Find element by className ".ABC"
- Find "span"-s inside that element
- Give those spans a class

To do those, follow these steps:

```js
// get the first element that matches .ABC
let parent = document.querySelector(".ABC");
// now parent is either an Element, or undefined/null

// if it's not null, we can call querySelectorAll
// get all elements inside the parent that are spans
let spans = parent.querySelectorAll("span");
// spans is now either an array of Elements, or undefined/null
// if it's not null, we can iterate over it
for (let span of spans) {
    span.classList.add('X');
}
```